# How to remove blank lines while saving dataframe as txt in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, txt

Imagine I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[2, 3, 4, 4, 2],
                    'b':[30, 19, 22, 10, 15],
                    'c':[200, 102, 260, 299, 400]})
```

I would like to save this as a txt, so I used this code:

```
with open (r'C:\Users\user026\Desktop\\' + 'example.txt', 'w') as wf:
    df_str = df.to_csv(sep="\t", index=None, header=False)
    wf.write('~A\n')    # adding a character before the real text
    wf.writelines(df_str)
```

It does save the dataframe as txt file, but it has added a blank line between each row. Here is the result:

example.txt

```
~A
2   30  200

3   19  102

4   22  260

4   10  299

2   15  400
```

What should I do to remove these blank lines in my txt file, so my result gets like this one below?

```
~A
2   30  200
3   19  102
4   22  260
4   10  299
2   15  400
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
df.columns = ['~A'] + ['']*2
df.to_csv('example.txt', sep='\t', index=False)
```

And you would get (there are extra two `\t` in the first row)

```
~A      
2   30  200
3   19  102
4   22  260
4   10  299
2   15  400
```

Or you can aggregate the text first to create a single-column dataframe and use `to_csv`:

```
(df.astype(str).agg('\t'.join, axis=1)
   .to_frame(name='~A')
   .to_csv('example.txt', index=False)
)
```

which gives (no more extra `\t`):

```
~A
2   30  200
3   19  102
4   22  260
4   10  299
2   15  400
```

Comment: Yeah! Thanks a lot!  The other suggestion to add line_terminator='\n' in df.to_csv also seems very good to me.